# Retrieving all details for a specific contact

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

I have the ID and Lookup key for a specific contact in Android.

From this, I need to extract any and all details saved by the user. Details including Contacts, Email ID's, Addresses, Phone Numbers, Fax, Facebook ID's etc.

This is what is given in the documentation

**PROJECTION TO RETRIEVE ALL DATA:**

```
private static final String PROJECTION =
            {
                Data._ID,
                Data.MIMETYPE,
                Data.DATA1,
                Data.DATA2,
                Data.DATA3,
                Data.DATA4,
                Data.DATA5,
                Data.DATA6,
                Data.DATA7,
                Data.DATA8,
                Data.DATA9,
                Data.DATA10,
                Data.DATA11,
                Data.DATA12,
                Data.DATA13,
                Data.DATA14,
                Data.DATA15
            };
```

But how do I know which fields relate to which field? These DATA{} fields are generic fields and the documentation is a little confusing. Can anyone help me parse the Cursor that this projection gives?

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details) I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check the `Data.MIMETYPE`, and depending on the mimetype, you can deduce which data value resides in which `DATA` item.

For example, if the `MIMETYPE` is `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`, then you can check the aliases described in this table to understand the values:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone#column-aliases

Alternatively, you can change your `PROJECTION` to be:

```
private static final String PROJECTION =
            {
                Data._ID,
                Data.MIMETYPE,
                Phone.NUMBER, 
                Phone.TYPE, 
                Email.ADDRESS,
                Email.TYPE,
                ...
            }
```

Since those aliases translate into the same set of constants (DATA1, DATA2, etc.) the performance will not be impacted, and the code might be more readable.